# Php Web Page Failed to display List of Products With Wamp Server

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I am developing E-commerce site by using php and wamp . I am trying to display list of products when I clicked the products hyperlink . But the problem is whatever link I clicked ,it is showing following errors ..

**Error in:sqlCat**

Here is my connection.php  code file ..

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "ecom1";

// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$db);

// Check connection
if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


?>
```

Here is php code for category.php file.

```
<div class="sidebar_box"><span class="bottom"></span>
                <h3>Categories</h3>   
                <div class="content"> 
                    <ul class="sidebar_list">
                    <?php




                                     $sqlCat= "select * from category where recordstatus='' order by sequence_order Asc";
                                       $exeCat = mysqli_query($con,$sqlCat) or die ("Error in:sqlCat");

                    $counCat= mysqli_num_rows($exeCat);
                    if($counCat>0)
                    { 

                       $classCat=1;
                       while($resCat= mysqli_fetch_array($exeCat))
                       {
                         $categoryname= $resCat["categoryname"];
                         $auto_number= $resCat["auto_number"];

                        ?>
                        <form method="post" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;" action="productcategory.php" id="frmdetailcat<?php echo $classCat;?>">
                          <input type="hidden" name="category" value="<?php echo $categoryname?>">
                          <input type="hidden" name="categoryid" value="<?php echo $auto_number?>">
                        </form>

                        <?php

                          if($classCat==1)
                          {
                          ?>
                          <li class="first"><a  style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="subform('frmdetailcat<?php echo $classCat;?>')" ><?php echo $categoryname;?></a></li>
                    <?php
                          }else
                          if($classCat==$counCat)
                          {
                          ?>
                          <li class="last"><a  style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="subform('frmdetailcat<?php echo $classCat;?>')" >
                          <?php echo $categoryname;?></a></li>
                    <?php     
                          }else
                          {
                          ?>
                    <li><a  style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="subform('frmdetailcat<?php echo $classCat;?>')" >
                          <?php echo $categoryname;?></a></li>
                    <?php
                          }
                          $classCat++;
                       }
                      }else

                      {
                      ?>
                       <li class="first"><a href="#">No Category is avaliable</a></li>

                      <?php
                      }
                    ?>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is the screen shot when i run the application ..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$con` is probably empty. You need to call `Connection.php` at the top of your `category.php` page.

```
// you have
<ul class="sidebar_list">
<?php

// you should have
<ul class="sidebar_list">
<?php
    require_once('..\db\Connection.php') ;
```

Comment: You have a capital `C` in the file name in your post (which may not matter on Windows). Also, you need to have the file name in quotes. And, the file needs to be in the same directory as `category.php` or in a directory covered by your `include_path`.

Comment: @Mohammad, I edited the code to use a relative path.

Comment: If `category.php` is in `onlineordering\include` then using `..\db` would be accessing `onlineordering\db\Connection.php`.

Comment: this is latest changes         require_once('..\onlineordering\db\connection.php') ; but still error Error in:sqlCat . Thanks you for time . do not know what to say

Comment: What do you get when using `mysqli_error($con)`? That should tell you the database error

Comment: I'm not suggesting you change. The function I suggested is `mysqli`. It tells you the error you are getting. If you don't know the error you cannot fix it.